# new google.maps.LatLngBounds() bound extend and center working random

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to put some markers on a map. The data is retrieved from a DB and read using JSON loop.

The markers a placed but I'm also trying to show all the markers on the map and center the view. This seems to work random I refresh the page and sometimes it shows the 3 markers and sometimes it shows just my starting LatLng which is just a random point in the middle of the island. If I zoom out the markers are there. So this seems to be a problem with the LatLng of the Markers sometimes not being extended in the loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(12.106058, -68.935192);
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            bounds.extend(myCenter);
            $.getJSON('map.php',function(data){
                if(data.success == true) {
                    if(data.CData.length > 0){
                        $.each(data.CData,function(index, value){
                        CID = value.CID;
                        Active = value.Active;
                        Name = value.Name;
                        Tel = value.Tel;
                        Lng = value.Longitude;
                        Lat = value.Latitude;
                        i=0;
                        addMarker(map, i, CID, Active, Name, Tel, Lat, Lng);
                        setBounds(Lat, Lng);
                        i++;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });

        function addMarker(map, i, CID, Active, Name, Tel, Lat, Lng){
            if (Active == 1){
                if (Lat != null && Lng != null){
                    //alert("loop start!");
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
                    var imageUrl = 'Images/default.png';
                    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl);                                            
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: markerImage,
                        title: Name,
                        zIndex: i          
                    });

                    image = '<img src="image.php?cid='+CID+'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" />';

                    var content = '<div class="">'+image+'<h4>'+Name+'</h4><h4><span class="label label-danger">Tel: '+ Tel +'</span></h4></div>';

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
                        content: content,
                        maxWidth: 370
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
            }               
        }

        function setBounds(Lat, Lng){
            var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
            bounds.extend(newLatLng);
        }               
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call to get the marker data happens asynchronously, i.e. it can finish after your calls to map.setCenter and map.fitBounds.  You should try and move those into either your addMarker function, or that's only executed when all the markers have finished being added, e.g.

```
$.getJSON('map.php',function(data){
    if(data.success == true) {
        if(data.CData.length > 0){
            $.each(data.CData,function(index, value){
                CID = value.CID;
                Active = value.Active;
                Name = value.Name;
                Tel = value.Tel;
                Lng = value.Longitude;
                Lat = value.Latitude;
                i=0;
                addMarker(map, i, CID, Active, Name, Tel, Lat, Lng);
                setBounds(Lat, Lng);
                i++;
            });

            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
});
```